# How to get the value of drop down selected in ajax in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am stuck up with the issue regarding the ajax drop down value selected = selected when it is edited or refresh

```
  <div class="form-group" id="maincat">
                    <label for="cat_desc" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select State</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select name="city_state" id="stateDrp">  
                                <option value="">Please Select State</option>  
                        </select>
                        </div>
                </div>

 function sel_city(val){
                 $.ajax({  
                    url:"<?php echo  
                    base_url();?>tdbadmin/countriesmanagement/getstate_drpdwn",  
                    data: {id: val},  
                    type: "POST",  
                    success:function(data){  
                    $("#stateDrp").html(data);
                    //$("#stateDrp").val(<?php echo $citydata[0]->country_id;?>);   
                 }  
              }); 

        }

setTimeout(function(){
sel_city(<?php echo $citydata[0]->country_id;?>);

}, 1000);   
$("#stateDrp option[value='<?php echo     $citydata[0]->country_id;?>']").attr("selected", "selected"); 

</script>
```

This was what i have tried but i could'nt get the selected value in the drop down please help

Comment: inside the `success` function after `$("#stateDrp").html(data);` try to put your code for `selected after it. `$("#stateDrp option[value='<?php echo     $citydata[0]->country_id;?>']").attr("selected", "selected"); `

Comment: i hope u r using <script> starting tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#stateDrp option[value='<?php echo $citydata[0]->country_id;?>']").attr("selected", true);
```